# List order rearrangement using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone please help me on this problem.
I have a list order like:

```html
<ul>
  <li class="parent">Parent item 1</li>
  <li class="no-parent"><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
  <li class="no-parent"><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
  <li class="parent">Parent item 2</li>
  <li class="no-parent"><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
  <li class="no-parent"><a href="#">item 4</a></li>
  <li class="no-parent"><a href="#">item 5</a></li>
  <li class="parent">Parent item 3</li>
  <li class="no-parent"><a href="#">item 6</a></li>
  <li class="no-parent"><a href="#">item 7</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want this like :

```html
    <ul>
      <li class="parent">Parent item 1</li>
      <div>
      <li class="no-parent"><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
      <li class="no-parent"><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
      </div>
      <li class="parent">Parent item 2</li>
      <div>
      <li class="no-parent"><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
      <li class="no-parent"><a href="#">item 4</a></li>
      <li class="no-parent"><a href="#">item 5</a></li>
      </div>
      <li class="parent">Parent item 3</li>
      <div>
      <li class="no-parent"><a href="#">item 6</a></li>
      <li class="no-parent"><a href="#">item 7</a></li>
      </div>
    </ul>
```

is this possible to make it using jQuery?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you want the dots nested? so that the children go further out?

Comment: You can't have a `div` as direct child of `ul`

Comment: It's not doable with only jQuery. You need custom implementation for that.

Comment: @VitaliiChmovzh it's not doable at all. UL accepts LI, not DIV

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan why not? It will produce semantically incorrect syntax , but overall wrapping each other items into <div> is doable.

Comment: @Pavlo it is not nested. All items are siblings for each others.

Comment: sadaf You shouldn't do that as @Eddie mentioned

Comment: is this possible to make a nested list? I mean no-parent item will be show as a child item of parent item. Hope you have got my point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to accept a semantically correct nested list, you could achieve that by using jQuery to loop through each `.parent` element and select each item after it until it hits the next `.parent` item using `nextUntil()`. Then, you create a new `<ul>` and append those children to it and then append the new `<ul>` to the parent `<li>`.

```js
// Select all of the .parents and loop through them.
$('.parent').each(function() {
  // Select all the following siblings starting from this .parent element until you reach the next .parent element.
  var $children = $(this).nextUntil('.parent');
  
  // Take the results and append them to a new ul element and then append that ul element to the current .parent li element.
  $children.appendTo($('<ul>').appendTo($(this)));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="parent">Parent item 1</li>
  <li class="no-parent"><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
  <li class="no-parent"><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
  <li class="parent">Parent item 2</li>
  <li class="no-parent"><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
  <li class="no-parent"><a href="#">item 4</a></li>
  <li class="no-parent"><a href="#">item 5</a></li>
  <li class="parent">Parent item 3</li>
  <li class="no-parent"><a href="#">item 6</a></li>
  <li class="no-parent"><a href="#">item 7</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You are great !!! how can you read my mind. I was thinking like this.. :) Thanks a lot.